# Running water sound from sink drain

Tags: plumbing

We occaisionally hear the sound of running water from the drain of an upstairs sink.  No water is running in the house and the other sink (his and hers) is quiet, as are others in the house.  The air conditioners drain away from the sink and out the side wall. When I turn water on and run it down the drain, the sound stops.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below the sink the drain pipe should include a trap, probably in the shape of a P turned sideways. The low part of the trap should remain filled with water. When it does not, sewer smells -- and/or sounds, as you've discovered -- can come up through the drain plumbing into the room.

The water in a trap can run low for a variety of reasons. A problem with the plumbing vents, infrequent use (evaporation), and leaking are some possible causes.

Comment: Check toilets for leaks in the tank or for over-filling. The toilet tank may be repeatedly drawing down and refilling, heard at a nearby drain.